# Issue with Salesforce Datetime formatGmt method

Tags: datetime

I have been experiencing a strange issue since Dec 27. When I  try to format a date to a string, it is giving me next year date. When I executed this in Workbench, I find that the `formatGmt()` method of Datetime class is actually giving me next year’s date.

So, in results, I am getting the date as `2015-12-29T11:59:12.988Z` but the corresponding string date (using YYYYMMdd) format is `20161229`.

[image]

This was working fine till Dec 27 and there has been no change to the underlying code.

I read the specs of the formatGmt method again – am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use small `y` instead of capital `Y`. This will give you correct output.

```
Datetime myDatetime = Datetime.now();
String myDatetimeStr = myDatetime.format('dd/MM/yyyy');
system.debug('=========='+myDatetimeStr);
```

---

IF you looked into this link

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

> The capital Y merge field is the WEEK YEAR - which from the 27th
>   December 2015 is IN 2016!
>
> The lower case y merge field is the CALENDAR YEAR - which will be 2015
>   as expected.

Comment: ahh. you nicked my magic answer ;) this question comes up 10 times every year at the end of the year.

Comment: @SimonLawrence Yes credit goes to you.  Thank you for finding out...

Answer (score 1):

please use year string in small case like `Datetime.now().formatGMT('yyyy/MM/dd')`. there is a difference between `'dd/MM/YYYY'` and `'dd/MM/yyyy'`. you can refer this link to understand in better way [Date and Time Patterns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)